How to have individual folders act as Repositories under a main Repository?
Is it possible to have a main Git Repository and each of the folders under said main repository be considered individual Repositories? I have several hundred folders under a main Repository and I don't want to have to clone the entire repo if I don't have to. I don't want to use submodules, sparse-checkout, branches or symlinks.
Current structure of repository framework:
https://github.com/mybusiness/infrastructure
Folders under said 'infrastructure' repository:
dev/infra-ansible/
dev/app-build/
I want to have the following listed as individual repositories that I can clone indivually and not cloning the 'raw' content since these will be private repostories that will get updated daily and/or weekly:
https://github.com/mybusiness/infrastructure/dev/infra-ansible
https://github.com/mybusiness/infrastructure/dev/app-build
It seems that GitHub doesn't support something like this, but I've heard rumors that GitLab does.

Does this answer your question? How do I create nested repositories in GitHub?

In a way, yes, but I don't want to use submodules, sparse-checkout, branches or symlinks. I think GitLab is capable of doing it. It seems that GitHub isn't able to. I just wanted clarification on it.

GitHub doesn't support something like this, because Git doesn't support something like this. If you want subdirectories to be considered individual repositories they must be individual repositories, that's the only way. To be continues…

…continue… Here your question becomes unclear. You said you want to download that individual repositories — no problem if they're separate repositories. But what about the main project? Do you want to clone it with or without nested repositories? If you always want to clone it with nested repositories — you need submodules, subtree or subrepo tools. If you don't want them — you want a magic wand, and StackOverflow is a bad place for searching magic wands, sorry.

If you think GitLab has something like what you want — could you please show us a public example?

In addition to submodules, subtree or subrepo you could also consider multi-repo tools like mr or Google's [tag:repo].
